# Help with Buddhist meaning of 麼

Tags: characters

麼 Occurs repeatedly in later Tang and early Song Dynasty Buddhist texts. Does anyone know of its Buddhist meaning, most translators disregard it. Thanks.

Comment: any sample text provided?

Comment: Usually, it is the transliteration of "ma". Some translators used 摩 or 末 instead.

Answer (score 1):

That character doesn't have a specific meaning, because it almost always used in a sequence of characters which represents the sound (not the meaning) of the original texts, that is usually in Sanskrit language.

It is like you call Jack by "杰克". The two characters mimic the pronunciation of the name Jack.